# int8_t chooses overloads that treat it like an alpha char

Tags: c++, stl, char, std

What I really want is an 8bit signed integer type. The problem is that under the covers we all know it gets aliased to a char where applicable. Well, for me, it’s applicable. So my dilemma is that I want to use c++ std lib containers and algorithms with my 8bit int, but the overloads  get picked according to the char it is, not the signed 8bit int I want it to be. Is there a way to cast into a numeric type or somehow imbue numeric traits without full blown wrapping or something? I specifically want to avoid casting into a short or int or other larger numeric literal type etc. thanks

Comment: The short answer is: no, there isn't.

Comment: What problems are you running into because of this?

Comment: @PeteBecker std::basic_string<T> [where T=short or T=int, signed or unsigned] handles zero just fine. std::basic_string<char> (aka std::string) does not.

Comment: `std::string` handles a `char` value of 0 just fine; it marks the end of a text string. After all, it’s a **string**, not a generic container. `std::vector<std::int8_t>` is the right choice for a variable-size array. So, aside from issues related to `std::basic_string`, what problems are you running into?